# How to send a JavaScript object from a registered event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

I’m having trouble sending an object from a registered event to a JavaScript function. Here’s the checkbox onchange code; in the `test()` function `figure` is the `object`:

```
$('#tblEntity').append('<tr><td><input type="checkbox" 
                checked="checked" 
                onchange=test("' + figure + '","' + id + '")
                /></td><td>' + Column.figure.text + '</td></tr>');
```

This is the `test` function:

```
function test(that, id) {
    alert(id+" "+that);
}
```

When I saw the registered function in the IDE’s run-time view, it was not formed correctly:

```
function onchange(event){
    test([object
}
```

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle so we can better help you.

Comment: @Legendary If you are going to bother editing, please do not leave broken English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/j608x6g7/

You are converting your Object to a String. Thus the string version of an object is: "[Object object]". You should pass a callback function that contains your object and your id.

```
// This is what you will put into the onChange
// event. It wraps 'figure' and 'id'. It's
// a function callback !
var callbackTest = function(){
     test(figure, id);   
}

// Your input checkbox
// Declared in jQuery but this is
// optional
var input = $("<input>")
    .attr("type", "checkbox")
    .attr("checked", "checked")
    .on("change", callbackTest)
```

Comment: @tchrist: king of capital letter ? :D ty ;)

Comment: Every thing is working fine but design is not as expected. the inner html is `<tr></tr><td></td><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"><td></td>EmpID'